# How to producing text models in pmml

Tags: r, pmml

`pmml` 4.2 supports text model as via `TextModel` element and transformations using `TextIndex` element

http://www.dmg.org/v4-2-1/Text.html and

http://www.dmg.org/v4-2-1/Transformations.html#xsdElement_TextIndex

I am working in R and currently `pmml` support for R does not provide text modelling. What tools can I use to produce text model `pmml` files. If no tools are available do I need to hand code the model?

Comment: Which R function do you use for training text models? Perhaps you could provide a small R code example.

Answer (score 1):

I found out after some research that currently none of pmml producing tools provide producing of Text Model or Text Index elements. The only way is to code it manually using the schema given at the DMG website http://www.dmg.org/v4-2-1/Text.html